# Вывести определённые данные из строки

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь

```
{"result":200, "data":{"lat": 55.753215, "range": 23.026, "lon": 37.622504, "time": 1588374174}}
```

Как из неё мне вывести только данные `lat` и `lon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас именно строка такого вида, то может помочь `eval`:

```
s = '''{"result":200, "data":{"lat": 55.753215, "range": 23.026, "lon": 37.622504, "time": 1588374174}}'''
dic = eval(s) # преобразуем строковое представление словаря в словарь
print(dic["data"]["lat"], dic["data"]["lon"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {"result":200, "data":{"lat": 55.753215, "range": 23.026, "lon": 37.622504, "time": 1588374174}}

print(dic["data"]["lat"], dic["data"]["lon"])
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 55.753215 37.622504
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
# ваш словарь
dic = {"result":200, "data":{"lat": 55.753215, "range": 23.026, "lon": 37.622504, 
"time": 1588374174}}

# вывод требуемых даных
data = dic.get('data')
print(data.get('lat'), data.get('lon'))
```

Вывод:

```
55.753215 37.622504
```